# How to 'hijack' an iframe Tag and put into a div?

Tags: javascript

I need some help.
My goal is to get the `iframe` tag that I have in my page and put it inside a `div` that I don't have on the page using **javascript**

What I have:

```
        var iframes = document.querySelectorAll('[data-name="youtube"]')
        for (var i = 0; i < iframes.length; i++) {
            var iframe = iframes[i];
            var createWrapper = document.createElement('div');
            createWrapper.setAttribute('id','youtubeVideo');
            iframe.style = "width:560; height:315 ; position: relative; border: none;"
            createWrapper.outerHTML = iframe.outerHTML.replace('data-src', 'src')
        }
```

I have an error that says "Element has no parent node"...
The goal is just to wrap this `iframe` on a `div` so I can give it style through javascript... I don't have access to the page and all needs to be done via this script...

the desired result would be:

```
<div id="youtubeVideo">
   <iframe ....> </iframe>
</div>
```

Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to append the new div to the DOM

```
  document.body.append(createWrapper);
```

```js
var iframes = document.querySelectorAll('[data-name="youtube"]')
for (var i = 0; i < iframes.length; i++) {
  var iframe = iframes[i];
  var createWrapper = document.createElement('div');
  document.body.append(createWrapper);
  createWrapper.setAttribute('id', 'youtubeVideo');
  iframe.style = "width:560; height:315 ; position: relative; border: 2px solid #333;"
  createWrapper.outerHTML = iframe.outerHTML.replace('data-src', 'src')
  
  // remove orig 
  iframe.parentNode.removeChild(iframe)
}
```

```html
<iframe data-name="youtube" data-src='123'></iframe>
```